# Google Sheets linking between sheets not updating

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I've 2 google sheets.  I have a 'Total' cell for a column in sheet 1.  In sheet 2 (which is in a separate workbook) I have included that 'Total' cell using IMPORTRANGE.  However if I now add additional rows in sheet 1 the 'Total' cell is at a different reference obviously.  However sheet 2 is ONLY looking at the original reference.  Is there a way of referencing sheet 1 'Total' cell in sheet 2 such that changes in the location of that cell in sheet 1 are automatically updated in sheet 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that it is simpler than I thought.  Instead of referencing the 'Total' cell as an absolute, I first named the cell to 'totalattendees'.  Then in sheet 2 instead of having an absolute reference of 'B12' or whatever I referenced 'totalattendees'.

Now regardless of what rows I add or delete in sheet 1 'totalattendees' is automatically updated as I would have expected and therefore sheet 2 keeps the correct value.